# Unable to hide statusbar in single UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, hide, statusbar

I want to hide staus bar in single view controller but my code is not working.
I'm using the below code

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

&

```
-(void)viewWillApper:(BOOL)animated{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: you want to hide one vc ya all vc

Comment: have you try my answer?

Comment: hi you get solution else i help you ?

Comment: what is problem with `prefersStatusBarHidden` ? it must be work! and second approach also seems to right for earlier ios versions. if you use ios 7 then try to add [super viewWillApper]; before hiding  and [super viewWillDisappear]; after showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add this value to plist: "View controller-based status bar appearance" and set it to "NO".

[image]

or

in

```
application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions write

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

or

Add following line in viewdidload

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES
                                        withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

and add new method

```
 - (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
          return YES;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have `View controller-based status bar appearance` set to `YES` in app's `plist`, put this code in the view controller:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

and if `View controller-based status bar appearance` is set to `NO`, do the following whenever you want to hide the status bar.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one it's help for me-:

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{

  return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide status bar on a single VC:

1) Add this value to plist:

"View controller-based status bar appearance" and set it to "YES"

2) Add following to viewWillAppear:

```
[self prefersStatusBarHidden];
```

3) Add new method:

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES; 
}
```