# Remove status bar color from a single screen if its set in app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistatusbar

I am setting status bar colour in appdelegate class as below.

```
- (void)transitionToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    withTransition:(UIViewAnimationOptions)transition
{
    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;

    //SET STATUS BAR COLOR
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
    {
        UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 20)];
        view.backgroundColor= [UIColor colorWithRed:0.96 green:0.96 blue:0.96 alpha:1.0];
        [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:view];
    }
}
```

When I try to remove it from a single screen I am failing. It keeps the background colour as I set in appdelegate but removes texts. I want to remove also the background.

Here how I try to remove the status bar:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

and status bar looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326804/hide-the-status-bar-on-iphone-on-a-single-view

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to hide statusbar in single UIViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717012/unable-to-hide-statusbar-in-single-uiviewcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

in info.plist add this View controller-based status bar appearance set YES

```
View controller-based status bar appearance = YES
```

viewcontroller based hidden set

Add method in your view controller.

Objective -C

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

Swift

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: prefersStatusBarHidden not even called. I added to plist.

Comment: plz can you try it on Device

Comment: Still same. Its not called.

Comment: ok..set application.setStatusBarHidden(true, with: .none) in your Appdelegate & then try whether getting called on not

Comment: I didnt get this.

Answer (score -1):

Add the following to your Info.plist:

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

This also works (iOS7+):

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

You also need to call:

```
setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

in say viewDidLoad().

Comment: What is the objective c version?

Comment: -(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return YES;
}
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];

Comment: This is not helping. Because its hiding uistatusbar from the whole app.

Comment: You just need to set No in other view controller

-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden { 
return NO;
 } 

[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];

Comment: There are over 50 views, so I guess this is not the best way.