# Add overlay to cover entire screen(including status bar)

Tags: ios, swift

I have an overlay `(UIImageView)` which should have a transparent background and alpha. How can I set the `imageview` such that it covers the entire screen? Currently, it covers the screen but not the `UIStatusBar`. I am adding the view in `AppDelegate's` main `window` as a `subview`.

The code:

```
    let overlay1 = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "overlay-image"))
    overlay1.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    overlay1.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    overlay1.alpha = 0.87
    overlay1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)

    overlay1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    overlay1.layer.zPosition = 1
    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate).window.addSubview(overlay1)
```

Comment: you don't want to show the statusbar, is it your question?

Comment: I want to show the status bar and add a view which covers the whole screen

Comment: you only need to set the constraints like @kuldeep said

Comment: I am using the imageview programmatically , is there any other way than using constraint

Comment: @AbhishekMaster Update your question with the code you have tried and maybe put a screenshot too

Comment: What frame did you provide to the `UIImageView` when creating it with code?

Comment: I have added the code above

Comment: I have tried it but the status bar remains on the top and image gets cut by 20px on top

Comment: I guess this question is not wrong to get `close vote` or `down vote`.

Comment: Where are you adding this `imageView`?

Comment: The vc in which I am declaring and assigning the overlay is from storyboard if it matters , I am adding it in the main window so it appears in fullscreen but it isn't working and I am also changing the status bar color programmatically if it matters as well

Comment: Where in `vc` in which method? And also share the code how are you changing the `statusBar` color as it is not inbuilt.

Comment: In the `viewDidLoad()` method I am managing the overlay and for the status bar color here is the code: `let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView

 if statusBar.responds(to: #selector()) {
            statusBar.backgroundColor = APPBAR_COLOR
        }`

Comment: Try adding in `viewDidAppear:`

Comment: Still the same :(

Comment: This is because of `statusBar` background color. Remove that code and check again.

Comment: Thanks , it worked :)

Comment: @AbhishekMaster you can learn more from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717012/unable-to-hide-statusbar-in-single-uiviewcontroller?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @AbhishekMaster I have answered for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion in comments found that changing the `backgroundColor` of `statusBar` is the reason why your code is not working properly.

By printing the `superView` of `statusBar` I found that `statusBar` is not added on `UIWindow` instead it is on `UIStatusBarWindow` which is probably above the `mainWindow`.

Also please don't use force unwrapping it can be cause of crash. At last I put a `guard` to fetch the `statusBar`, to check if it responds to `backgroundColor` property, to fetch its `superView` and adding the overlay on this `superView` got it working.

Your check for `respondToSelector` is also wrong. See below code it works as per your requirement.

```
guard let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView, statusBar.responds(to: NSSelectorFromString("backgroundColor")), let superView = statusBar.superview  else {return}

statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

let overlay1 = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "overlay-image"))
overlay1.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
overlay1.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
overlay1.alpha = 0.87
overlay1.frame = superView.bounds

overlay1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
overlay1.layer.zPosition = 1
superView.addSubview(overlay1)
```

**Note: Changing the `statusBar` color is not recommended. You can set its style to `default` or `light`.**

Answer (score 0):

Okay I just tried with something and it worked. Just use it in your `ViewController` like:

```
// You should be using viewDidAppear(_:)
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let window = appDelegate.window {
        let windowFrame = window.frame
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: windowFrame)
        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "TakeOff") // use your image
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.2) // replace green with the color you want
        window.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}
```

> But, remember one thing. It's not a good idea to add an image view as
>   an overlay. You should always use a `UIView` as an overlay and add the
>   image view as a sub view to that overlay.

**Screenshot:**
[image: Overlay image view]